# Dynamically loaded elements are not in the HTML source code

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, loading

I am fetching an attribute of a div from a page which loads the elements dynamically upon scrolling to the bottom of the page. There are 10 div's on the page initially and upon scrolling 10 new div's are loaded each time dynamically to the page.

My script looks like this:

```
var arr = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML.match(/data-username="([^"]*")/gm); // I want the value from the attribute data-username
alert(arr.length); // size is 10

window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); // scroll to bottom to load 10 divs dynamically
arr = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML.match(/data-username="([^"]*")/gm);

alert(arr.length); // size is still 10 but should be 20
```

Why is the array size still 10? How can I get all the 20 divs and iterate through them?
I took a look at the HTML source code and the problem is that the dynamically loaded div's are not there... How am I supposed to get the dynamically loaded elements?

Comment: Have you given the elements chance to load before the second call to `getElementsByTagName`?  Since this line of code is immediately after the scroll to the bottom, it will run before any asynchronous code is run to fetch other elements.

Comment: Seems like you should be listening for a scroll event, and then placing the second getElementsByTagName call in that event's callback.

Comment: Also, if you just do a plain old view source you won't see dynamically loaded elements in the code. You need to use a browser's developer console to see the generated source.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are doing an ajax call to get the additional data, and you should wait for those elements to be available in the DOM (once it's complete) before doing things with them. That's quite easy with jQuery (as you had that as a tag)

- http://api.jquery.com/load/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/